# Process "accountsd" has over 500% CPU usage

Tags: macos, performance, cpu

I'm on Catalina 10.15.6 on a MacBook 2019 (16-inch) and one hour ago after startup my mac started  with an extremely loud fan and overheating. As Im writing this even the typing is lagging behind.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? I closed all apps running already and restarted several times, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you got caught in the bug many people believe was caused by 10.5.7 x https://mrmacintosh.com/catalina-10-15-7-update-accountsd-using-400-if-using-icloud-mail/ great details.

Comment: This is interesting indeed. But whats more interesting, is the fact that I did not install 10.15.7 yet. I'm still on 10.15.6 :D

Comment: I retract my cause being .7 - it seems people have issues on 10.15.5 and 6 as well - it's not clear yet how many "issues" and "contributing" factors trigger this. Maybe it's a client-server interaction that the update triggers more reliably than just running an older build - but the problem was there before the update?

Answer (score 1):

Alright after several unsuccesful restarts, Diagnostics (starting mac while pressing D), recovery and safe mode starts. I did a "force quit" of this accountsd process and after that, I made a hard shutdown of my mac (holding power button for 10 sec). Apparently this seems to reset the SMC of the Mac.

Now everything is working fine again. The accountsd process is at 0% CPU and I can use my mac in the usual way.

What I cant say is: Did the "force quit" of said accountsd process resolve the issue or the SMS reset?

For anyone having the same issue and finding this thread: I would try both and see if it works for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how a hard power-down would reset the SMC.

Comment: Today it started again, so unfortunately this was no long-term solution

Comment: The linked duplicate question seems quite clear on how to stop it. Force-quitting it will only delay it happening, not prevent it.

Comment: Want to edit this answer and work through each of these "fixes" and report which works for you? https://mrmacintosh.com/catalina-10-15-7-update-accountsd-using-400-if-using-icloud-mail/ That ordering of steps is for a business remediating hundreds of Macs. for me at home, I try the easy ones, then reinstall Mojave from the App Store... We've had 100% success following that checklist

Comment: Thank you @bmike. Currently, I do not have this problem, but if it starts happening again I will read through this article.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this, but I had the same problem about an hour ago, waking up to loud fan and an accountsd running at 360 %CPU with my idle remaining being 16%. I forced the commerce to quit and securityd to quit, then my accountsd. the User went down from 64% to 5%, which stopped the overheating. I do not understand how this works, but it would be good for you to try to.

P.S. it may ask you for authentication to your (online e.g. icloud) account? Don't, it restarted my commerce and the accountsd went back to the massive load.

Comment: Hey! I was just typing my own answer while you posted yours :D

Indeed I did the same and force quit the process. As explained in my answer I also force shut down the mac by holding down the power button and now it seems to work. Can't say if it was the force quit or force shutdown (SMC reset) which lead to the solution. But reading your answer I assume it would be enough to just force quit the process.

Comment: Unfortunately it was no long-term solution. Today it started again -_-